# python tkinter canvas feature, trying to use StringVar-s to draw arcs

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

im trying to create an arc with tkinter canvas widget, but whatever I do, I cant get the create_arc function to work. I tried assigning values to normal python variables in the main function body, but that doesnt work either. Here is my full code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
emasektor = StringVar()
def arvutapalgad(*args):
    try:
        sissetulek.set(x+y+z)
        emasektor.set(float((x/(x+y+z))*360))
        isasektor = 90
        lastesektor = (z/(x+y+z))*360
    except ValueError:

**raam.create_arc(20, 20, 180, 180,start = 0,extent=emasektor.get(),fill='red')**
```

Comment: This has way too much irrelevant code to slog through. Post the minimum code needed to exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example that works.  Build up from this until a bit at a time until it does not work.  That should tell you what is causing the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
can = tk.Canvas(root)
can.pack()
arc = can.create_arc(100,100,200,300, fill='red')

root.mainloop()
```

Or start with your code and cut or comment out until it does not 'work'.  Also, when posting a question, be more specific than 'does not work'.  If there is a traceback, post it.

Comment: everything until the create_arc function works, the traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Priit/Documents/PROGEMISHARJUTUS/t2rn4/t2rn4.py", line 70, in <module>
    raam.create_arc(20, 20, 180, 180,start = 0,extent=emasektor.get(),fill='red')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2290, in create_arc
    return self._create('arc', args, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2287, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

Comment: basically i need to somehow convert the stringvariable into something create_arc could use, but i have yet to find a way to do it

Comment: Use a DoubleVar.get(), or float(stringvar.get())